# Using MUP returned a container Errors about nonexistent endpoints and containers are normal

Tags: mongodb, docker, meteor, mup

I have been using this `MUP config` for the `deployment` until recently. When I encountered an issue and I had to `stop, reboot the Instance multiple times`.

Then, This causes the meteor app container to shut down and the MongoDB container is running just fine but wasn't accessible through an `SSH tunnel on a MongoDB GUI` (but running `systemctl status mongo` shows active status: `activating`.

I troubleshoot and run `docker ps -a`. It shows the MongoDB container only as a `running` container and the meteor app container completely shutdown.

I tried `running the MUP deployment` in an attempt to get `the meteor app container up` and running.

However, I got an error `Removing docker containers. Errors about nonexistent endpoints and containers are normal.`

[image]

I run the `mup setup` command successfully and then I tried running `mup reconfig` and I got the same above error, I have attached the screenshot of the error below.

[image]

To Reproduce this error

1. Create a [meteor app](https://www.meteor.com/) with [Iron-meteor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iron-meteor).
2. Setup an Instance (Ec2).
3. Setup Deployment with [Meteor-up](https://meteor-up.com/)
4. Deploy your app with Meteor-up.
5. SSH into the instance and run cmd `docker ps`. Should see at least two running containers, app and mongo respectively.
6. Run a cmd to `stop` the `app container` while the `mongo container` is `running`.
7. Finally, Goto your project and redeployed with `mup`

Should see a similar error as above. for `step 6` restarting the instance in my case shut down the two containers and I was able to get the mongo container back up and running.

However, I couldn't get the app container running, so I tried redeploying with the expectation that a new app container would be created if it doesn't exist on the instance.

UPDATED!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but in my experience, mup likes a fresh instance better than an existing one.

My first step would be a `mup stop` command. This will shut down the docker instances. Then you can remove them with `docker rm`, and you can remove the images with `docker rmi`. Then do a `mup setup` again, followed by a `mup deploy`.

If the first one doesn't work, you can basically start with a fresh vm, as in the droplet or ec2 instance. This is generally quite successful.

Comment: Thanks @Mikkel . Running the `mup stop` command will shut down the instance. However, My fear is losing the data on the database. is there a way I can recover the data

Comment: Oh, you are running a Mongo server there too. It's arguably better to use a hosting service for Mongo, and then you don't run the risk of losing any data. Given that your mongo server is still running, you should be able to connect to it and back up the data before you proceed.

Comment: Yes... I was using the Meteor version 1.4.x and the database is on the same server.
So. restarting the instance multiple times shut down those containers... got me on the brink of losing the data as well.

However, I recovered the database by starting the shutdown mongo container.

Comment: It's all good now... I had to spin up a new instance and migrate all setups. Thank you

Comment: I'd tried maintaining an external DB but it won't work. I ended up using internal setup

Comment: That may be a firewall issue, you need to allow the public IP of your meteor server to access the database